# How to edit "begin{proof}"

Tags: proof-package

How to edit the `begin{proof}` to show "Demonstração" instead of "Proof."? I don't want use `newtheorem{dem}{Demonstração}` because I want the blacksquare in the end.

Comment: did you try `\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Demonstração}`

Comment: are you really using the package `proof`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `\proofname` macro (of course, it is better to use `babel`, as the next answer suggests):

```
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Demonstração}
```

Comment: You are right, of course

Answer (score 4):

You have to do nothing so long as you use `babel` with `amsthm` and its `proof` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % recommended
\usepackage[portuges]{babel} % or brazil

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Exercício para o leitor.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Similarly (but more complicated) with `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % recommended
\usepackage[portuges]{babel} % or brazil

\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
\newtheorem*{proof}{\protect\proofname.}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Exercício para o leitor.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```